# What graphical Bitcoin wallet for Ubuntu integrates with the system (Notify OSD, Global Menu, etc)

Tags: linux, gui, bitcoin

I'm looking for a graphical Bitcoin wallet for Ubuntu. It should have these features:

- The ability to use a remote blockchain (not having to download the blockchain onto the computer)
- The ability to create multiple addresses, with labels

It would be nice, but not necessary, if it had:

- Integration with Ubuntu, such as using Notify OSD, the Global Menu, and the HUD

Can someone give me a recommendation that fits these requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Electrum**](https://electrum.org/) (License: GPLv3)

- uses a remote blockchain (you can choose among several public [servers](http://electrum.qc.to/)), and
- it automatically creates new addresses until a (configurable) [gap limit](https://electrum.org/faq.html#gap-limit) of unused addresses  is reached. IIRC, it has the ability to label them, too.

I don’t know if, or to which extent, it integrates with Ubuntu’s notifications, HUD, or Global Menu.

It’s [available from Ubuntu’s packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/saucy/electrum). (For manual installation on 12.04, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/281233))

Answer (score 4):

Since I saw this question today, I've been fiddling with various Linux Bitcoin Wallets.

**[Multibit](https://multibit.org/)** seems to be the best fit for your needs. You can create an arbitrary number of addresses, with labels.

I think it's impossible by definition to have a *local* wallet without a *local* blockchain. If you need your wallet's blockchain to be online, you probably need an online wallet. However, you *can* reset your local blockchain if needed. (Correct me if I'm wrong, I'll be happy to edit the answer)

With Multibit, you can...

- Create multiple wallets, and multiple addresses for each wallet.
- Create labels for your addresses.
- Generate QR Codes for your addresses.
- Create descriptions and categories for your wallets.
- Check the current exchange rate to USD.
- Send and Request Bitcoin.
- Review transaction history.